# Postgres: add unique integer to results?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgres 9.6. I have a query like this:

```
SELECT name, count(spend) as spend FROM mytable GROUP BY name;
```

This produces results like `Dave,40000`.

I would like to add a unique identifier to each result (yes, I know the name is already a unique identifier, but I would like a numeric one). So I would like results like `1,Dave,40000`.

It doesn't particularly matter what the unique identifiers are as long as they're numeric, but they might as well be integers.

Is there an easy way to do this with Postgres?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A window function:

```
select row_number() over(order by name) as ui, name, count(spend) as spend
from mytable
group by name;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use row_number

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY name) AS consecutivo, name, count(spend) as spend FROM mytable GROUP BY name;
```